# Can't use bindings in this context?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

So I have this code and I can't use the bindings!

```
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="File name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Image Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource fic}">
                                            <Binding Path="FileName" />
                                        </MultiBinding >
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                                <TextBlock Margin="16,0,0,0">
                                    <Binding Path="FileName" />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

**Long boring exception removed**

---

```
                                <TextBlock Margin="16,0,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <Binding Path="FileName" />
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
```

... Seems to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind the text of a textblock through its children.

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={x:Static t:PathToNameConverter.Instance}}"  TextAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="56" MaxHeight="50" />` worked...

Comment: `<TextBlock Margin="16,0,0,0">
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <Binding Path="FileName" />
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>` worked!

Comment: @Vercas, @SLaks is right.  `<TextBlock><TextBlock.Text>...` is equivalent to `<TextBlock Text="..."`.  Both binds to the `Text` property.  If you put the binding *inside* the `<TextBlock>` tags, it will try to bind to the children (or content) property instead.

Answer (score 2):

Things inside `<TextBlock>` tags are items contained inside the text block, which can be a whole lot of spans and other text fragments.

If you need to bind the text in the text block, you need to bind to the `Text` property, as you've done in your question.  It is a DependencyProperty that supports this binding.

The items inside the text block does not support direct binding, nor does it support directly putting binding objects in there.  However, you may put in another control with a DependencyProperty that is a binding though.

Comment: Ah, sorry but SLaks' answer was quicker and led me to solving my problem.